# Browser not connecting to server with websocket

Tags: javascript, python, heroku, websocket, tornado

I am hosting my app with Heroku and using websockets. When the browser sends a request the connection fails due to this error message:

**Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://shrouded-dawn-5557.herokuapp.com/ws**

In my javascript file I create a new websocket object as:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://"+ location.host +"/ws");
```

Why is this not making the connection to the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by enabling websockets in Heroku:

```
heroku labs:enable websockets -a myapp
```